# Declaring an optional class field using templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, std

I am using templates in an embedded  environment where I need to statically declare everything. 
I would like to know if there is any way of declaring an optional field in a class using templates or similar technique.

Now in one of the classes I am trying to do something like this ...

```
template<typename Filter, typename Compensation.....> 
class MeasurementChannel {

private:
  if constexpr( !std::is_same<Compensation, void>){
    Compensation _comp; // this is an optional field
  }

  ....

  ....

};
```

Now this doesn't work and in the real example I have maybe 4+ different pluggable components like Compensation that makes partial specialisation a problem because because I would need 16  specialisations just to deal with the different combinations of void in each of the optional positions.

The best way I have come up so far is to create a null class (NullComp in this case) that implements the basic interface but does nothing and gets substituted by the user when they don't want that component functionality as part of the templated class. Depending on the compiler optimisation level, most of the code that would be generated is optimised away, but I would like to be able to guarantee that nothing is created in the first place. .

So my question basically boils down to is there any way in templates of optionally declaring a field as part of a class. I.e is there some technique that gives the equivalent of using std::enable_if with methods.

Alternatively am I just trying to do this wrong and there is a simple elegant way of composing templates that reaches the same end goal using some completely different technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can partly specialize it:

```cpp
template<class Filter> class MeasurementChannel<Filter, void> {};
```

2. Alternatively, to not copy all the class code to partial specialization, you can only specialize the relevant part:

```cpp
template<class Compensation> class CompHolder {
protected:
    Compensation comp; // don't start identifiers with underscores
};

template<> class CompHolder<void> {};

template<class Filter, class Compensation> class MeasurementChannel
    : CompHolder<Compensation>
{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution, using conditional inheritance.

```cpp
template<bool Enable>
struct field_1 {};

template<>
struct field_1<true> { t1 member1; };

template<bool Enable, bool Enable1>
struct field_2 : field_1<Enable1> {};

template<bool Enable1>
struct field_2<true, Enable1> : field_1<Enable1> { t2 member2; };

template<bool Enable2, bool Enable1>
struct main_type : field_2<Enable2, Enable1> {
    // body
};
```

This gets cumbersome for too many fields. There might be a way to make this variadic that I'm not thinking of.